# Disable CUPS and CUPS-BROWSED in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, printing, services, systemd

The accepted solutions in other questions, ie:

```
echo manual > /etc/init/cups.override
echo manual > /etc/init/cups-browsed.override
reboot
```

Don't work in 16.04. I don't wish to uninstall `cups` as I'll occasionally need it, but I don't want the service to start automatically on startup.

How can I achieve this in 16.04?

Answer (score 38):

Since Ubuntu 16.04 aka Xenial is using `systemd` as init, you have to use `systemctl` to control/start/stop services.

In your case the lines as follows should do the job.

```
systemctl stop cups
systemctl stop cups-browsed
systemctl disable cups
systemctl disable cups-browsed
```